# Отправка СМС с помощью AT-команд

Tags: putty, com-порт, at

Имеется Huawei E171 с СИМ-картой Теле2. Карта рабочая, при установке в телефон СМС успешно отправляются.

С помощью Putty открываю порт и пытаюсь отправить СМС с помощью АТ-команд:

```
AT

OK

AT+CMGF=1

OK

AT+CMGS="+7923*******",145<enter>
>Hello<ctrl-z>

+CMS Error: 500
```

Какие варианты? Просьба не объяснять, что ошибка 500 - это неизвестная ошибка и ее сложно идентифицировать, это я и так знаю. Просьба поделиться мыслями, опытом, что это может быть. Пробовал менять номер центра обслуживания (не знаю, правильный ли использовал номер, правда), пробовал разные форматы номера, а также отправку через предварительное сохранение в черновики (AT+CMGW) и отправку через (+СMSS). Повторюсь, что СИМ-карта рабочая и проверена на телефоне.

Comment: Что такое ,145? Пробовали без этой части?

Comment: Естественно, 145 указывает на формат номера (+(код страны) ...)

Comment: Посмотрите https://www.zabbix.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-28800.html Там была похожая проблема. Мне кажется, что разнца в инициализации модема, отключении эха и м.б. в отсылке \r ??? В общем тут экспериментировать надо, а у меня такого оборудования нет

Comment: По-моему там 145 лишнее, и кавычки лишние тоже, вот на хабре есть статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/133085/

Comment: @nick_n_a, кому-то стоит почитать документацию.

Comment: Модем в сеть то вошел? `AT+CREG?`

Answer (score 0):

Второй строкой добавьте
AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0